# Generics and amount of methods in class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a doubt and I cannot find where in the `Java specification language` is defined (which I'm sure it is).

I have this hierarchy:

```
public interface Top<T extends Serializable>
{
    public String someMethod(T arg);
}

public class SubString implements Top<String>
{
    @Override
    public String someMethod(final String arg)
    {
        return "";
    }
}

public class SubSerializable implements Top<Serializable>
{
    @Override
    public String someMethod(final Serializable arg)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And I execute this piece of code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(SubString.class.getMethods().length); // outputs 11
    System.out.println(SubString.class.getDeclaredMethods().length); // outputs 2
    System.out.println(SubSerializable.class.getMethods().length); // outputs 10
    System.out.println(SubSerializable.class.getDeclaredMethods().length); // outputs 1
}
```

In the `getMethods` returning array for `SubString` class there are two `someMethod`, one with the signature `Serializable` and one with the signature `String`. Even in the `declaredMethods` both are present.

How could I tear apart those that are not "callable"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-callable one is marked as synthetic method, you can check it with `Method.isSynthetic()`.

According to [JLS 13.1. The Form of a Binary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1):

> 7. Any constructs introduced by a Java compiler that do not have a corresponding construct in the source code must be marked as synthetic, except for default constructors, the class initialization method, and the values and valueOf methods of the Enum class.